# How do you grab files with an extra dot extension in them for gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

My team has started using a file naming convention for our angular app that makes files look like this:

`report.module.js
report.controller.js
report.service.js
report.factory.js`

Our gulp file currently needs to grab each of these individually so our jsSources looks like this:

```
var sources = [ path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/index.module.js'),
path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.module.js'),
path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.factory.js'),
path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.service.js'),
path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.controller.js')]
```

but I'd like it to look like

```
var sources = [path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/index.module.js'),
          path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.*.js')
]
```

So as to run the index.module.js(start of the app) first, then everything else in the app/ folder

How can I do a catch all to grab anything.anything.js, I tried the more obvious solutions (e.g. * . *.js, * .js, etc) but nothing seems to work. I know this is silly in this example but it has far reaching implications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you simply do `[path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/index.module.js'), path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.js')]`? Shouldn't you also include your `*.modules.js` just after `index.module.js`? What about `'/app/**/*.(module|factory|service|controller).js'`

Comment: The point is to avoid having to callout every possible option,  there could be many. *.js didn't work oddly..